# How to get json date from javascript date object?

Tags: javascript, json

Hi is there any native way how to get json typed date from Date object? I mean I need to get date for today in this format: 2013-04-05... (I know I can use strings but I want something more native...)

Comment: There's no JSON Date object/representation...everyone uses a string of some sort.  It's the biggest missing piece in the JSON spec IMO.

Comment: Do you mean a string representation of the JS date object in ISO format?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: As of Javascript 1.8.5 there is a native `toJSON` method of the Date object.

Comment: @winterblood this JavaScript versioning you use. No one really uses it. It's more of an internal Mozilla thing. I think you meant ES6 and more specifically [this](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date.prototype.tojson). Also, it's still not a JSON date, it's still just a stringification.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: [It's present in ES5 as well](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.44)

Comment: @Bergi Ah nice! TIL. Makes sense.

Comment: [The JSON Specification](http://json.org/) has no special Date type.  There is no "native" date format.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Even using the ES versioning system each browser implements proposed features at different times, so claiming a feature is in ES6 is just as inexact regarding actual browser support as saying it is in Javascript 1.8.5, as there are ES5 compliant browsers beyond just Firefox which already implement ES6 features. But yes, it is just stringification of a date object, thus I did not post it as an actual answer, but as a potentially informative comment.

Answer (score 0):

In ES5 compliant browsers, there's [Date.prototype.toJSON](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.44) and [Date.prototype.toISOString](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43) which does exactly the same thing.

If feature detection shows *toISOString* is missing, you can add it to Date.prototype using the code suggested at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).